# gRPC Protobuf's Timestamp.FromDateTime() returns null on PHP

Tags: php, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto3

I cant get my head around what I am doing wrong here.

```
use Google\Protobuf\Timestamp;

$timestamp = new Timestamp();
$dt = Carbon::now();
$pt = $timestamp->fromDateTime($dt);
```

Carbon is a simple PHP API extension for DateTime so it should work but instead I get a null value for $pt

Comment: You have a typo. `$d` should be `$dt`.

Comment: @JohnConde good eye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong, in case for future reference, the way is done is so:

```
use Google\Protobuf\Timestamp;

$timestamp = new Timestamp();
$dt = Carbon::now();
$timestamp->fromDateTime($dt);
```

and then use the $timestamp variable as needed.